# Sticky Pop-up Implementation

Tags: jquery, asp.net, plugins, popup

I want to implement sticky pop-up which will open on click of icon which is stick to left side of screen, its position will be fixed on screen.
Sample image of pop is added below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9lgg.png)

and it will be a control in asp.net, I want to implement it using jquery.

I searched for plugins which I can use to implement this sticky pop-up but I don't get what I want.

So if anyone knows any plugin for it or any sample code please share it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOVerflow. The purpose of StackOverflow is to help developers that have problems with a specific code and not to recommend plugins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need a plugin to implement it. An example of such scenario is the following.

```js
$(function() {
    $("#MyButton").click(function() {
        $("#Contents").toggle();
    });
});
```

```css
#MyButton {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
#Contents {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 120px;
    background-color: lightgray;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="MyButton">Click Here</div>
<div id="Contents">
    Contents
</div>
```

Comment: Can we Slide it from left to right with button and button text will change once popup open?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. For the contents you want it to slide and appear from the left side of the screen? About the button it is not a button. It is a div which can be converted to button if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sanatsathyan/for98z1f/2/)`Demo`

```js
$('.icon').click(function() {
  $('.popup').toggleClass('show');
});
```

```css
.body {
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #EEE;
}

.icon {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 10px;
  z-index: 3;
}

.popup {
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: #cccccc33;
  position: fixed;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.popup.show {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="body">
  <button class="icon">
icon
</button>
  <div class="popup">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9lgg.png" width="450">
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this might help!!!